# Calling setContentView for animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

In my application we are achieving the page-animation by using setContentView every time the animation occurs. The layout contains just an image so its definitely not too heavy. But are there any other problems in calling setContentView again and again on the same activity. Will it cause memory leaks or something similar.

Tried searching the net but since our layouts contain only the imageviews the onSaveInstance also doesn't have much to do.

Let me know your inputs.

PS I know about ViewFlippers and other waqys of animation. Was just curious if its advisable not to call setContentView in an activity repeatedly and Why?

And I can't create a tag for setContentView if any of you can please tag this question with that tag.